# PyDev cannot find modules in the project source folder

Tags: python, import, module, pydev, pythonpath

Okay, so this is not the first time I've had this problem, but it really has driven me to the edge this time. The problem is this. I am developing something on Linux and Windows, sharing the workspace via dropbox and switching between interpreters. Occasionally, the project stops being executable. The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SomeUser\Dropbox\Workspace\NetworkNamingGame\src\naminggame\analyzer.py", line 13, in <module>
    from naminggame import util
ImportError: No module named naminggame
```

Interestingly, NetworkNamingGame\src is *the* source folder of the project. And naminggame is *the only* package there. Package explorer successfully recognizes it as a package and shows the relevant icon.

I realize this could be caused by source folder changing paths (although I thought they were relative paths), so I have repeatedly tried to remove and readd the project source folder to the list of source folders, "forced restore internal info"s, cleaning the project, removing PyDev configurations and retrying all of the above, but no luck. When I check the python interpreter command that is executed by PyDev, I can see that the source folder is not in the PYTHONPATH. The only solution I've found is to import the whole thing into a new project. Not a very good solution if you ask me.

I would be only moderately pissed off if this was an external folder, but it is right there! It is the first and only folder it should be looking at with my configuration. Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it without starting everything from scratch?

Versions bit:

**Eclipse SDK**

Version: 3.6.1

Build id: M20100909-0800

**PyDev**

Version: 1.6.5.2011020317

And the contents of the naminggame folder upon request:

```
$:~/Dropbox/Workspace/NetworkNamingGame/src/naminggame$ ls
abc.png          analyzer.py  concatenate_logs.py   game.py      logs          profiler_output  server.py                            triangle.gif
Analyzer.log     circle.gif   concatenate_logs.py~  __init__.py  net.py        rectangle.gif    simulation.py                        util.py
analyzer_old.py  client.py    csv_generator.py      log          pentagon.gif  Server.log       success_data_50-150agents.anova.csv
```

Comment: Could you give a print out of the files contained in the naminggame folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please upgrade to the latest PyDev (2.2.1 at this time), as it should 'fix' that for you. If you still have the issue, please post a screenshot of your PyDev package explorer for this project.